# Problems with monitoring processes launched by child_process spawn on Windows

Tags: c++, node.js, windows, exception, performance-testing

Mein purpose is simply to launch an exe using node.js. In case the application is unexpectedly terminated, the exception should be catched and logged in a protocol. An exception is thrown thru the following statement in a c++ project:

```
throw std::string("NOT X or x!!!");
```

My Javascript is:

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
var cp = spawn(process.env.comspec, ['/c', 'myExcepTest.exe', '', '']);

// **doesn't work**
cp.on('uncaughtException', function(err){
    console.log("Caught exception: " + err);
});
cp.stderr.on('error', function(err) {
    console.log(err.toString());
});
cp.stdin.resume();
cp.stdin.setEncoding('utf8');
cp.stdin.on('data', function(data) {
    cp.stdout.write(data);
});

// **does work**
cp.on('exit', function(code){
    console.log("Child exited with code: " + code);
});
cp.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
    console.log(data.toString());
});
```

My questions are:

1. Is it a good practice to use node.js to monitor a process on
       windows?
2. Is it possible, to use node.js to catch an exception on
       windows?
3. How to correctly pipe the stdin to stdout in a node.js
       script?

Sorry for my poor English ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Depends on why you're monitoring the process I suppose.
2. There is no `uncaughtException` for child processes. The reason being is that there is no standard way for catching such things, considering the child process could be any kind of program.
3. You can't pipe the `stdin` of a child process to its own `stdout`, because [`stdin` is a Writable stream](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_stdin) and is an input to the child process (not an output from it), so `stdin` will never have `data` events.

Comment: to "why you're monitoring the process": the motive is quite straightforward. I just wanna try to automate the tests of my application in the following way: launching the exe, recording its cpu and ram usage, in case of exception kill the process and protocolling the exception text and end time.

Comment: Well, typically when a process dies unexpectedly, it exits with a non-zero status code (or signal). Both of these you can check in the child process object's `close` event. Any `stdout`/`stderr` output is available of course, but parsing that from regular program output may not be easy.